# Edit to GCC spec file is not being used during compilation

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, linker, loader

I'm working through the current LFS (Linux from scratch) book, section 6.10.

When I attempt to compile the dummy file it fails with

```
/tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my investigation I noticed that the spec file that I wrote isn't being used when executing GCC. E.g.

```
root:~# gcc -v
Reading specs from /tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/specs
...

root:~# sed -n '/startfile_prefix_spec/{N;p}' /tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/specs
*startfile_prefix_spec:
/usr/lib/

root:~# gcc -dumpspecs | sed -n '/startfile_prefix_spec/{N;p}'
*startfile_prefix_spec:
```

Is there something wrong with gcc reading the spec file I created?

Comment: I fixed the issue with the error. /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so{,.1} were pointing to the wrong location and hence why it could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the error. /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so{,.1} were pointing to the wrong location and hence why it could not be found.